# textbox with rounded corners and drop shadow

Tags: c#, wpf, roundedcorners-dropshadow

I'm trying to replicate a textbox like this:

[image: Textbox with drop shadow]

The background outside the textbox will be taken care of by the parent container.

To my knowledge there are 4 items I need to take care of:

- Rounding corners
- Adding an inner drop shadow to the top and right hand side
- Adding an outer drop shadow to the left and bottom sides
- Avoiding the text in the text box inheriting the shadow effects.

I've borrowed code from [WPF rounded corner textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779777/wpf-rounded-corner-textbox) and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225076/Creating-Inner-Shadows-for-WPF-and-Silverlight but I just don't have enough grasp on WPF to do this.

Code at present:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxBaseControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="8"
                ClipToBounds="True">
            <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,10,10,0" Margin="0,-11,-11,0">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="8"/>
                </Border.Effect>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" TargetName="Bd"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Width" Value="Auto">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" Height="25" Margin="5">
        Text
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This renders as:

[image: CurrentCode]

Problems are that the drop shadow is outside the rounded corners on the top and right; the text is shadowed; and i've not figured out how to add a shadow to outside of left & bottom.

If I remove

```
CornerRadius="8"
```

from the BorderThickness then I get a rectangle with the shadow on the inside.

I'm open to any pointers in how to solve this.

Comment: I'll be honest and say that the text-box you've illustrated is ugly. It isn't pretty. I just felt it needed to be said.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add a corner radius to your second border to get the drop shadow fixed on the top and right.

Comment: @Dai, may I ask why you don't like it ? the outside of the box is the background of parent container - you're seeing a snippet of what will be a linear gradient.

Comment: @Lee O, i've discovered that the corner radius makes it block out more - because its a concave curve on the inside and it blocks out to 2 sides of the square on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `Background` other than null or transparent in the `Border` that has the `DropShadowEffect`, otherwise any elements contained by it will also get the dropshadow. Also, play around with the [Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.direction%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the `DropShadowEffect` to get the shadow in different angles

Comment: This removes the border itself for some reason. I'll keep experimenting