# TextBox border radius style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I checked similar questions but I couldn't figure out the underlying logic.

I am trying to add `CornerRadius` to a `TextBox` in a `WPF` project.
Here's what I tried so far:

In `App.xaml` I created a `Style` that I intend to reuse:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="27"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5.5"/>

   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

Adding: `<Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" Value="5"/>` didn't work. However, the following worked, but with side effects (all borders where rounded):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
   <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
</Style>
```

I want to keep the styles separate and basically use them like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ExampleTb" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
```

Can you please help me/ point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF rounded corner textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779777/wpf-rounded-corner-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very simple to achieve this, just follow these steps:

Step 1. Add a textbox to your window, right click on your textbox and select "Edit Template \ Edit a Copy..."

This will take you to the control template designer.

Step 2. Check this picture:
https://postimg.org/image/9h5ng8p9t/

P.S. I find blend better suited to design controls.

Comment: Fabulously simple and clear! Cheers! Really... amazing!

Comment: This link is no longer active.

Comment: please don't link to off site pictures, either embed or preferably provide the text