# WPF Animation on TextBox Border On IsMouseOver when Not Focused

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am implementing custom styles for the TextBox type in a WPF app I am working on, and I want to implement different animations for when the cursor is over the TextBox, and when the TextBox is actually focused.  How my code currently works is the `IsMouseOver` trigger fires and starts the animation even when the TextBox already has focus.  I do not want this, I want the `IsMouseOver` animation to play only when the TextBox is not focused and when the user hovers over the TextBox. Is this possible in XAML?

Here is my existing code:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border x:Name="PART_Border" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        CornerRadius="4">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" TargetName="PART_Border" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#0079CB" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#CBCBCB" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#5A5A5A" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#CBCBCB" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Width" Value="Auto">
                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the `IsMouseOver` animation to play only when the TextBox is not focused **and** when the user hovers over the TextBox.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

It's actually just a small adjustment to your existing code. You need to use a `MultiTrigger` instead of the *simple* `Trigger` to account for `IsMouseOver` **and** the Focus. Depending on your exact requirements you might want to use `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, `IsKeyboardFocused` or `IsFocused` for the second condition.

```xaml
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" 
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#5A5A5A" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" 
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#CBCBCB" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks @Manfred Radlwimmer

Comment: And yes, part of this code came from another stackoverflow answer I saw about applying corner radius to textbox's.  When I said "my code" I merely meant the code that I submitted in the question.  Original article found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779777/wpf-rounded-corner-textbox