# Weird WPF Round TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, rounding

I am new to WPF and I am trying to do a rounded corner textbox. There are a lot of examples I gather from here. However I cannot seems to make it work. Below are the two ways I tried and the results I obtained.

**First Way:**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SubTransparentTextBoxBG" Color="#ffffff" Opacity="0.12"/>        
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SubTransparentTextBoxBG}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24px" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>                
        </Style.Resources>            
    </Style>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Apparently all my Setters took effect but not the Corner Radius

**Second Way:**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SubTransparentTextBoxBG" Color="#ffffff" Opacity="0.12"/>        
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SubTransparentTextBoxBG}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24px" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#000" BorderThickness="2" Background="#fff"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style.Setters>

    </Style>
```

**Result:**

[image]

This time, only the Round Border takes place and the rest of the Setters' property are overwritten.

Can Someone Please Help to point out what are the mistakes in these two ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF rounded corner textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779777/wpf-rounded-corner-textbox)

Comment: You should override a `ControlTemplate`

Comment: Some controls have mandatory template elements (parts) which must be part of the `ContorlTemplate`. When those parts are missing the functionality of the templated control might get broken. To know the parts of `TextBox`  visit [TextBox Parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates#textbox-parts). To know the parts of all WPF controls visit [Control Styles and Templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates). This links also contain an example of the actual `Style` and `Template`.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I used the Examples stated there but it will not work. Not sure why. I will try overriding a Control Template too. I am just curious why the same solution (Like the First Way) works for other people and not me, am I missing something

Comment: Also in order to use the templated control as usual, you should bind template control properties to the templated parent (e.g. `<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ... />`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to give the `TextBox` rounded corners is to overwrite the template.

The following is your `Style`, but fixed. It now contains the mandatory parts with their mandatory naming: a content host named *PART_ContentHost*. In order to make the style setters work, you need to bind the template's controls (in this case the `Border` properties) to the appropriate properties of the templated parent (the `TextBox`) using `TemplateBinding`.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Style.Setters>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource SubTransparentTextBoxBG}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="24px" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="Segoe UI Semibold" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
          <Border CornerRadius="10"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

            <!-- The required part with the required name -->
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Wrapping the `TextBox` in a `Border` with rounded corners will still leave the `TexBox` with sharp corners that will overlap the rounded corners of the surrounding `Border`.

Some controls have mandatory template elements (parts) which must be part of the `ContorlTemplate` and have a special name. When those parts are missing or the name doesn't match the required name, then the functionality of the templated control might get broken. To know the parts and their names of `TextBox` visit [TextBox Parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates#textbox-parts). To know the named parts of all WPF controls visit [Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates). This links also contains an example of the actual Style and Template.

An alternative approach to get the required template parts is to select the control you wish to template and then open the XAML designer view. Right click on the selected control and select *Edit Template*. In the popup select *Edit a Copy*. A dialog opens. Here you can give the extracted template a name and set the location where the extracted template will be moved to. Now you can edit this template which already has all the required parts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew I was missing something somewhere!